# How to link a 32bit dll statically(!) into a 64bit C/C++ windows application?

Tags: dll, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

a few years ago I was a Windows application developer.
In the last years I am dealing with kernel and system software.
Now:
I have a customer who tells me that he has a 64bit C/C++ application with
specific functionality. This functionality is a dongle request
and comes from an external 32bit dll.
He says that this functionality is given although I can not see the
DLL in memory. 
If I delete the DLL, the 64bit application is still loaded.

That means the 32bit DLL is somehow a static part of the 64bit application.

Can that be true nowadays?

And if so how can I achieve that with Visual Studio?

Best regards
Burkhardt

Comment: I don't believe what you are describing is possible in a direct sense.  Our product (when running 64 bit) uses a 32 bit executable to perform 32 bit operations when they're required.  It communicates via named pipe with the 64 bit client DLL when required.

Comment: That is an architectural solution, but: you'll find the 32bit dll in memory. But I can load the application so it is not a statical link(!) to the 32 bit dll, and I can not find it in memory so it is not dynamically ( LodLibrary..( ) ) reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have found on StackOverflow.com it is not possible to load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit application (or vice versa) dynamically or statically. There are however a few workarounds.

See the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938217/184528
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720902/184528
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11642165/184528