# python tkSnack is giving me errors

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to manipulate sound using [the Snack Sound Toolkit](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/), however when I try to run their demo code I get an error. I followed the installation instructions like it said in the readme file.

CODE:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
from tkSnack import *

root = Tkinter.Tk()

initializeSnack(root)

s = Sound(load='ex1.wav')
c = SnackCanvas(height=100, width=400)
c.pack()
c.create_waveform(0, 0, sound=s, width=400)

Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

ERROR:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "G:\workspace\voice test\MinWave.py", line 8, in <module>
        initializeSnack(root)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkSnack.py", line 21, in initializeSnack
        Tkroot.tk.call('eval', 'package require snack')
    _tkinter.TclError: couldn't load library "C:/Program Files/Python/tcl/snacklib/libsnack.dll": invalid argument
```

I am running windows 7 x64 with python 2.7.6

Thanks, Logan

Answer (score 1):

I have had this exact same problem with a DLL (different DLL). I found the [***inpspectExd***](http://www.silurian.com/inspect/index.htm) tool, mentioned in [***this thread***](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/_iyMJT5oDRM), really useful and I think it has helped me figure out what was wrong...

Apart from being quite cool, the inspectExe tool let me see that my DLL was 32-bit and the python distro was 64-bit. It also had a test load feature so I knew the DLL was a good one and could be loaded along with all its dependencies...

My DLL was 32-bit and my Python distribution was 64-bit and [***64-bit python can't load a 32-bit DLL***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642134/can-i-use-32bit-dll-or-exe-in-64bit-python)... doh!

I'm heavily suspecting my problem is this 64/32 mismatch... still to actually verify this. Perhaps your problem is same 64/32 problem??

Answer (score 0):

Did you "install"  Snack. It requires, as far as I remember, you to copy files manually.

> Snack v2.2.10
>   Install the Snack libraries by moving tkSnack.py to C:\Python23\Lib\\r\n\r
>   and snacklib\ to C:\Python23\tcl\ (modify as necessary).
>   A description of the demos can be found in python-demos.txt

Your code runs fine here. Im Win7 x64 2.7.6 as well

Comment: yes i did that. but just to make sure the \r\n\r isn't part of the file path is it?

Comment: and for me python is in a folder called 'Python' not 'Python23' but that shouldn't make a difference should it?

Comment: Have You checked that the dll is there?

Comment: yep libsnack is there along with libsnackogg, libsnacksphere, libsound, and two .tcl files pkgIndex.tcl and snack.tcl their file path is C:\Program Files\Python\tcl\snacklib if that helps at all

Comment: I really don't know, I have moved my Python install to same dir as you, and your script still runs smoooothly.. Sorry

Comment: tkSnack.py should be in the Python Lib folder and if you run that it has a self-test mini player that will show if it is all working correctly. I just copied my old copy from a Python 2.7 folder into Python 3.4, fixed up the  syntax a little and had it work in Python 3. You must have the tcl parts in <pythonroot>\tcl\snack2.2 and tkSnack.py in <pythonroot>\Lib. If it doesn;t load snack you can try manually performing the commands in initializeSnack (where it calls Tcl to load the snack package).