# load COM dll in python

Tags: python, com, pywin32

I have a very simple DLL which exposes a COM object SimpleATLComLib.SimpleCom.

I have correctly registered it in the registry and I succeeded to use it both in a C# project (I successfully added the reference to SimpleATLComLib) and in VBA, but I can't get it to work in python.

In C# I simply added the reference and wrote

```
using namespace SimpleATLComLib
```

in VBA

```
Dim x as SimpleATLComLib.SimpleCom
```

I tried to load it in python by using `win32com.client`

```
win32com.client.Dispatch("SimpleATLComLib.SimpleCom")
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

How am I supposed to call it?

Comment: Does 32-bit/64-bit mode match between them? Please refer to this article. [VBS: how to check presence of a registry key in x64.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b772e43-b875-40fa-b8cf-7740546e5a3b/vbs-how-to-check-presence-of-a-registry-key-in-x64?forum=isvvba), [Can I use 32bit dll or exe in 64bit python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11642134/9014308).

Comment: the whole chain is x64