# Setting meld as git mergetool with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, git-merge, meld

I've tried setting meld as my mergetool to use with git doing:

```
git config --global merge.tool meld
git config --global mergetool.meld.path c:/Progra~2/meld/bin/meld
```

As outlined in answers to questions like:

[How to set Meld as git mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956509/how-to-set-meld-as-git-mergetool)

I used to have this working on my old work machine but now on my new machine where I have Python3 installed instead of 2.7 I am getting the following error whenever I try git mergetool:

> C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/mergetools/meld:
>   c:/Progra~2/Meld/bin/meld: C:/msys64/MINGW32/bin/python3.exe: bad
>   interpreter: No such file or directory

Any ideas what extra steps I need to make to get this to work with Python3?

EDIT: I have tried pointing directly to Meld.exe too but that causes the following crash:

[image]

Comment: Found the error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11642134/2988730. Not a duplicate, just a hint.

Comment: Here you go: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/issues/376. Given what I found in my answer, I think this is a reasonable report to file.

Comment: Looks like the issue has been fixed in the new release version (not by me).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.../bin/meld` script is mostly there for reference. You should set

```
git config mergetool.meld.path "C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe"
```

You don't need to use `Progra~2` notation unless you really want to for some reason.

The only issue that I am having is that it is not properly picking up the installed dependency extensions in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/lib`. You need to add `C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/lib` to your `PATH` environment variable, either with `SET PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/lib;%PATH%`, or through the "Edit Environment Variables for your account" somewhere in control panel/start menu.

**Alternative Approach**

If you open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\bin\meld` in a text editor, you will see that it is a shell script that is intended to be run in `python3` (called from `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe` most likely).

The first line of `meld` reads:

```
#!C:/msys64/MINGW32/bin/python3.exe
```

This issue does not pop up when using `Meld.exe` because it does not use the script through a python interpreter.

It is unlikely that the python interpreter is installed at that location on your machine. Instead, you can replace the shebang line to point to an existing interpreter. For example, on my machine, `meld` starts with:

```
#!C:/Users/MadPhysicist/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe
```

This still won't be enough for the script to find the `meld` package and all the installed GTK, cairo, etc. DLLs, so you have to tweak both the python and system paths. Insert the following before the line `import meld  # noqua: E402` (line ~78):

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join((melddir, os.path.join(melddir, 'lib'), os.environ['PATH']))
sys.path[0:0] = [os.path.join(melddir, 'lib/python3.7/site-packages')]
```

I was not ever able to get the first line to set up Cairo, GTK, etc. correctly for `meld`. You can, however, skip the first line and just install the packages using conda or pip. You will still need to insert the meld package into `sys.path`.

Keep in mind that `meld` is compiled in 32 bits, as evidenced by the `x86` in the install folder. You can only run it with a 32-bit python interpreter if you use the included DLLs, which may require additional installation. You do not need a 32-bit interpreter if your environment contains all the necessary packages already.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That has gotten me one step further. Now getting the following error: '  File "c:/Progra~2/meld/bin/meld", line 79, in <module>
    import meld.conf  # noqa: E402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meld''

Comment: Just saw your edit. I did actually try that originally, figured it wasn't meant to work due to the error I got. I've added it to my original question.

Comment: @Plog. I got meld to show up. Turns out it's a weird path thing. Not sure why it's happening. Most likely, you had PyGtk, PyCairo, PyGObject, etc. installed in your Python 2.7 environment.

Comment: @Plog. I wouldn't select this just yet. I'm going to look at the source of meld.exe, which I think should just be setting up the script's environment. Might get a PR out of this, or at least a bug report.

Comment: Wow super appreciate all the work you put into this! I'm a little confused though. Adding that folder to the PATH variable hasn't resolved the issue for me. Am I supposed to install the 32 bit interpreter too?

Comment: Oh actually I tried it on that simple reproduction case you added in the bug ticket and it works there but on the repository i'm working on mainly I still get the same error which is very odd...

Comment: Nevermind. A restart of the PC resolved that! Thanks so much!